# How to display 250k cells in a grid with phaser3/webgl?

Tags: webgl, phaser-framework

I need to display 250k  cells/rectangles at once, when drawing more than 20k rectangles, the frame rate drops below 30fps.

I have nothing running once the grid is drawn, yet the fps stays low, not sure why that is. I would also need to update some of the cell color once in a while.

I have tried using lines, instead of rectangles (vertical and horizontal lines to form a grid), but performance seems to be about the same.

Code: https://playcode.io/638898/

Assuming drawing this many rectangles are not currently possible at 30fps, what would be some other alternatives?

Thanks.

**Solution**:
I ended up using lines instead of rectangles, like Denis [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029502/1190892) suggested to get over 60fps while displaying 250k cells.

```js
var config = {
  width: 1200,
  height: 1200,
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: '#canvas',
  scene: {
    create: create,
    update: update,
  },
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var graphics;

// Change size.
let isize = 600;

let data = [];

data = [...Array(isize)].map(x => Array(isize).fill(0));

let hspace = 5;
let size = {
  x: isize,
  y: isize
}

let fps = 0;
let fpsText;

function create() {

  graphics = this.add.graphics({
    lineStyle: {
      width: 1,
      color: 0xffffff,
      alpha: 1
    }
  });

  // Draw rectangles.
  for (let ix = 0; ix < size.x; ix++) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      graphics.beginPath();
      graphics.moveTo(ix * hspace, 0);
      graphics.lineTo(ix * hspace, size.y * hspace);
      graphics.stroke()
    });
  }

  for (let iy = 0; iy < size.y; iy++) {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      graphics.beginPath();
      graphics.moveTo(0, iy * hspace);
      graphics.lineTo(size.x * hspace, iy * hspace);
      graphics.stroke()
    });
  }

  fpsText = this.add.text(50, 50, 'Static Text Object', { fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 48, color: '#00ff00' });

  this.cameras.main.setZoom(.3);
  this.cameras.main.setPosition(-400, -400);

  // Move camera with mouse drag.
  this.input.on('pointermove', (pointer) => {
    if (pointer.isDown) {
      this.cameras.main.scrollX -= (pointer.position.x - pointer.prevPosition.x) * 1.5;
      this.cameras.main.scrollY -= (pointer.position.y - pointer.prevPosition.y) * 1.5;
    }
  })
}

function update() {
  fpsText.setText(Math.floor(this.game.loop.actualFps) + "fps");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.23.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calls to `requestAnimationFrame` are completely redundant as the `create` function does not present any content to the display. It is only called once.

Reduce GPU state changes by reducing the number of render calls. `graphics.stroke` is a state changing function, as all the lines use the same style you need only one call to `stroke` rather than many

**NOTE** I am unfamiliar with Phaser's internals, it may or may not force state changes on `stroke`, however other API's defiantly do! It is good to be aware of and write efficiently.

```js
const config = {
  width: 1200,  height: 1200,
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  parent: '#canvas',
  scene: {create, update},
};
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
const isize = 600, hspace = 50, size = {x: isize, y: isize};
var graphics, fps = 0, fpsText;

function create() {
  var i = Math.max(size.x, size.y);
  graphics = this.add.graphics({ lineStyle: {width: 1, color: 0xffffff, alpha: 1}});

  graphics.beginPath();
  while (i--) {
      if (i < size.x) {
          graphics.moveTo(i * hspace, 0);
          graphics.lineTo(i * hspace, size.y * hspace);
      }
      if (i < size.y) {
          graphics.moveTo(0, i * hspace);
          graphics.lineTo(size.x * hspace, i * hspace);
      }
  }
  graphics.stroke(); 

  fpsText = this.add.text(50, 50, 'Static Text Object', { fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 48, color: '#00ff00' });

  this.cameras.main.setZoom(.3);
  this.cameras.main.setPosition(-400, -400);
  this.input.on('pointermove', pointer => {
    if (pointer.isDown) {
      this.cameras.main.scrollX -= (pointer.position.x - pointer.prevPosition.x) * 1.5;
      this.cameras.main.scrollY -= (pointer.position.y - pointer.prevPosition.y) * 1.5;
    }
  })
}

function update() {
    fpsText.setText((this.game.loop.actualFps | 0) + "fps");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.23.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```